# Save the_content into custom field

Tags: custom-field, the-content

Is it possible to save the content (inside the WP WYSIWYG (`the_content`)) into a custom field?

**This is what I have so far:**

```
add_action('edit_post', 'save_content_to_field');
function save_content_to_field($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;

    if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
        $content = get_the_content($post_ID);
        add_post_meta($post_ID, 'desc', $content, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you already have your custom field working? If so, share what code you're using so far and I'm sure we can help with the saving issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK!

I found this way and this might be useful to someone:

```
add_action('edit_post', 'save_content_to_field');
function save_content_to_field($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;

    if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
        //$content = get_the_content($post_ID);
        global $post;
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);

        add_post_meta($post_ID, 'desc', $content, true);
       }
     }
```

Comment: I would just apply the filters on output the way WordPress does with `the_content`? I don't see what you gain doing this, other than potentially breaking something, since your code lacks the context of a front-end request.

Comment: @Milo can you please elaborate (if possible)? I don't understand much of programming, but I would like to learn. Thanks

Comment: Your code applies `the_content` filters, which is what WordPress does only on display, it doesn't save the results. You're also applying them outside of the loop and not in the context of a page view. Some shortcodes enqueue scripts/styles, and rely on checking the context of display (is_single, is_archive, etc.), they may be broken when you try to display that pre-rendered content.

Comment: @milo so I need to remove the `apply_filters`?

Comment: I would move it from the save function to wherever you're displaying the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the content with `$_REQUEST`, Try the below code:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'save_content_to_field');
function save_content_to_field($post_ID) {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['content'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_ID, 'desc', $_REQUEST['content']);
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**
With the below code if you want to sore with shortcode support:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'save_content_to_field');
function save_content_to_field($post_ID) {
    $post = get_post($post_ID);
    $result = apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content);

    if($result) {
        update_post_meta($post_ID, 'desc', $result);
    }
}
```

Comment: working, but... this is getting the content as HTML and I would like to save it like it's inside the WP WYSIWYG. Just imagine, If I have a shortcode inside there, I would like to save it like I see it on the editor.

Comment: The post updated.